# Hyperledger fabric channel create failed: Principal deserialization failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create channel to test my fabric environment, and I don't use docker instead I am running the actual executable itself. However, the creation failed with errors.

Error on the orderer：

```
2018-09-04 20:36:55.034 CST [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 251 Principal deserialization failure (MSP OrdererOrg is unknown) for identity 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
>2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 252 0xc00000f0e8 gate 1536064615035064391 evaluation starts
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 253 0xc00000f0e8 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 254 0xc00000f0e8 principal evaluation fails
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 255 0xc00000f0e8 gate 1536064615035064391 evaluation fails
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 256 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 257 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [policies] func1 -> DEBU 258 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ OrdererOrg.Writers ]
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 259 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 25a == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [policies] func1 -> DEBU 25b Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Orderer.Writers Consortiums.Writers ]
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 25c Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Writers
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 25d == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 25e [channel: roberttestchannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.136.100:54494 because of error: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
2018-09-04 20:36:55.035 CST [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 25f Closing Broadcast stream
2018-09-04 20:36:55.037 CST [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 260 Error reading from 192.168.136.100:54492: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2018-09-04 20:36:55.037 CST [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 261 Closing Deliver stream
2018-09-04 20:36:55.037 CST [grpc] infof -> DEBU 262 transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2018-09-04 20:36:55.037 CST [grpc] infof -> DEBU 263 transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
```

Error on the peer:

```
2018-09-04 20:36:55.007 CST [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
```

I have tried to reboot or delete all the project files. But it didn't work.
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Can you provided more information? Which version are you using? Using Node SDK or fabric-tool to create channel?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the condition from you description:

1. modifying the `crypto-config.yaml` and `configtx.yaml` file to create your own fabric network.
2. using `cryptogen` and `configtxgen` to generate the channel artifacts and keycerts file
3. then your may use `fabric-tool` or Node-SDK to handle the fabric network like enroll the user, create channel and join channel.
4. the error threw out when your are create channel

In the head of the log, it shows that `MSP OrdererOrg is unknown`. That problem may cause by after using orderer certs signed the channel-creating request then the client sent the request to the orderer. It is fine that you use the order to sign the channel-creating request, only if you configured your Signature policy to your target member. Like setting the Rule like:

```
    Policies:
         Readers:
             Type: Signature
             Rule: "OR('OrgOrderer.admin','OrgOrderer.client')"
         Writers:
             Type: Signature
             Rule: "OR('OrgOrderer.admin')"
```

If you are left the Policies setting to blank, it will follow the [default policy](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/policies.html#policy-defaults).

The logs similar to `Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers` do shows that your signature is not valid. If you want to know more detail about what specific policy configuration, using the `configentx` to inspect the `channel.tx` or `genesis.block`:

```
configtxgen -inspectBlock  ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block -configPath ./crypto-config/example.com/ >genesis.json
configtxgen -inspectChannelCreateTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx  --configPath ./crypto-config/example.com/ >channel.json
```